# Blank space after error message in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I output error message with this code:

```
<script>
   const successNotification = window.createNotification({
    theme: 'error',
    showDuration: 5000,
    closeOnClick: true
   });    
   successNotification({title: 'ERROR',message:'Category name is required
'});            
</script>
```

After Category name is required it is an blank space, I want to be like this:

```
<script>
       const successNotification = window.createNotification({
        theme: 'error',
        showDuration: 5000,
        closeOnClick: true
       });    
       successNotification({title: 'ERROR',message:'Category name is required'});               
    </script>
```

Here is my php code:

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', $this->lang->line('category'), 'trim|required|xss_clean',
        array('required' => $this->lang->line('category_required')));

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('',''); 

            if ($this->form_validation->run() === false) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('submit-error', validation_errors());
                    redirect($this->agent->referrer());
              }
```

And in my view I have this:

```
<script>
   const successNotification = window.createNotification({
    theme: 'error',
    showDuration: 5000,
    closeOnClick: true
   });    
   successNotification({title: 'ERROR',message:'<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('submit-error'); ?>'});            
</script>
```

How I can remove blank space after error message in output?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved after some research. I will put here may be will help

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('submit-error', trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', validation_errors())));
```